# IOS development how to solve the capture signal handler by covering problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I want to make both the existing singal handler in the project and my own singal handler co-exist so that both can properly capture singal.

`typedef void (*signalHandler)(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context);
static signalHandler previousSignalHandler = NULL;
void signalExceptionHandler(int signal, siginfo_t* info, void* context)
{
    NSMutableString *mstr = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [mstr appendString:@"Stack:\n"];
    void* callstack[128];
    int i, frames = backtrace(callstack, 128);
    char** strs = backtrace_symbols(callstack, frames);
    for (i = 0; i <frames; ++i) {
        [mstr appendFormat:@"%s\n", strs[i]];
    }
    BYLOGI(@"%@",mstr);
    [BYCrashCacheHelper saveAppCrashDataWithCrashInfo:mstr];
    if (previousSignalHandler) {
        previousSignalHandler(signal, info, context);
    }
}
void signalRegister(int signal)
{
    struct sigaction action;
    action.sa_sigaction = signalExceptionHandler;
    action.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER | SA_SIGINFO;
    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
    sigaction(signal, &action, 0);
}
void judgePreviousSignalHandlerAndSignalRegister(int signal)
{
    struct sigaction old_action;
    sigaction(signal, NULL, &old_action);
    if (old_action.sa_flags & SA_SIGINFO) {
        previousSignalHandler = old_action.sa_sigaction;
    }
    signalRegister(signal);
}
void installSignalHandler(void)
{
    judgePreviousSignalHandlerAndSignalRegister(SIGHUP);
    judgePreviousSignalHandlerAndSignalRegister(SIGINT);
    judgePreviousSignalHandlerAndSignalRegister(SIGQUIT);

    judgePreviousSignalHandlerAndSignalRegister(SIGABRT);
    judgePreviousSignalHandlerAndSignalRegister(SIGILL);
    judgePreviousSignalHandlerAndSignalRegister(SIGSEGV);
    judgePreviousSignalHandlerAndSignalRegister(SIGFPE);
    judgePreviousSignalHandlerAndSignalRegister(SIGBUS);
    judgePreviousSignalHandlerAndSignalRegister(SIGPIPE);
}`

I found the above method in some blogs, but after debugging, I found that it can not get to the previous handler.
Excuse me, how to get the previous handler correctly, and avoid the handler coverage problem?

Comment: I tagged Objective C as well. Do note that the C standard guarantees next to *nothing at all* in the signal handler. I am almost certain that constructing Objective-C objects in the signal handler is asking for trouble.

Comment: Did you use a translator program for your question? It is hard to understand what problem you are encountering, because the translation is not really clear.

Comment: I want to make both the existing singal handler in the project and my own singal handler co-exist so that both can properly capture singal

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain this information

Comment: I have re-edited the question, thank you for your help.

Comment: You have *only one* variable for previous signal handler! Perhaps you should have one for each signal (an array)!

Comment: Debugging through the breakpoint, I found that any signal can not get the previous singal handler.

Comment: <PRE>                                                                                                                   
void judgePreviousSignalHandlerAndSignalRegister(int signal){}
 </ PRE>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  This method can not get the previous singal handler, how to modify it?